# Android.mk & Application.mk are not generated by Android Studio

Tags: java, android, c, android-studio, android-ndk

I'm trying to compile a C program and connect it with JNI. It's been a few years since my last encounter with Android NDK. As far as I remember, Android Studio's ndk project used to have a JNI folder with `Android.mk` and `Application.mk` file.

The `Android.mk` file was responsible for compiling the native code and `Application.mk` file was responsible for creating a lib file of the jni code that would be used on Java side.

However the Android NDK project generate by Android Studio 2.3.2 seems completely different.

The JNI folder is replaced by `cpp` folder that contains `CMakeList.txt` and a `.c` file. I couldn't find `Android.mk` file and `Application.mk` file anywhere. However the app works fine when I run it using play button.

But what if I add a C program Eg. MyCProgram in `cpp` folder that has its own `Cmake` file that call Cmake files of other C programs connected to it. I'm not sure how would I do that.

I have tried to compile the Android NDK project using `ndk-build` but it gives me this error:

```
Android NDK: Could not find application project directory !
Android NDK: Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it.
```

Which probably is related to the missing Android.mk and Application.mk files.

Please excuse my ignorance in Native C development in Android and kindly tell me where can I find the `Andriod.mk` & `Application.mk` files and what changes have been introduced on NDK side that I should know?

Comment: There is no language C/C++. C and C++ are different languages. Sure you use C, not C++? `cpp` folder sounds like the latter.

Comment: @Olaf Yes I aware that C and C++ are different languages. Let me edit C/C++ in the question. The generated project has .c file in the cpp folder

Comment: _"where can I find the Andriod.mk & Application.mk files"_ There are none. If you create a project with C++ support in Android Studio nowadays it will assume that you want to use CMake, and will generate a CMakeList.txt for you. If you still want to use `ndk-build` you can create the Android.mk and Application.mk files yourself, then change the `cmake` lines in your gradle script to `ndkBuild`, and change `path "CMakeList.txt"` to `path "Android.mk"`.

Comment: @Michael does it mean, if I have a huge C program with multiple Cmake files, all of them can be referenced from the CmakeList.txt file and then I can reference the files of the C program in my JNI code, right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with CMake so I can't answer that.